# Self referential has_many through in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read lots about self referential classes in Rails, but am still having problems getting them working.

I have a class of Articles and I want them to be able to refer to each other, from a source article to an outcome article - and then be able to find the reverse.  So I'm trying to do a has_many through, using another class called Links.

My schema is

```
  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "links", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "source_id"
    t.integer  "outcome_id"
    t.string   "question"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

The models are

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links_as_source, :foreign_key => "source_id", :class_name => "Link"
    has_many :sources, :through => :links_as_source

    has_many :links_as_outcome, :foreign_key => "outcome_id", :class_name => "Link"
    has_many :outcomes, :through => :links_as_outcome
end
```

and

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :source, :foreign_key => "source_id", :class_name => "Article"
    belongs_to :outcome, :foreign_key => "outcome_id", :class_name => "Article"
end
```

I can create articles in the console, and I can link articles together, using `a.outcomes << b` but the link table is only storing the outcome_id, not the source_id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After calling `a.outcomes << b` are you calling `a.save`?

Comment: I got this to work in the end.  I changed the names - I don't know if that mattered.  I did read somewhere that source was a silly name to use for something.

So this is what works:
  create_table "article_relationships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "child_id"
    ...
  end

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    ...
  end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work in the end.  I changed the names - I don't know if that mattered.  I did read somewhere that source was a silly name to use for something.

So this is what works:

My schema

```
create_table "article_relationships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "parent_id"
  t.integer  "child_id"
  ...
end

create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  ...
end
```

My article model

```
has_many    :parent_child_relationships,
            :class_name     => "ArticleRelationship",
            :foreign_key    => :child_id,
            :dependent      => :destroy
has_many    :parents,
            :through        => :parent_child_relationships,
            :source         => :parent

has_many    :child_parent_relationships,
            :class_name     => "ArticleRelationship",
            :foreign_key    => :parent_id,
            :dependent      => :destroy
has_many    :children,
            :through        => :child_parent_relationships,
            :source         => :child
```

Comment: This has saved me hours and hours and should be set as the answer. Thank you so much!

I could find solutions for self referential has many through, going from the parent, but was stumped to get the association working from the child. This solved it brilliantly!